# How to read response from soap apis

Tags: .net, xml, api, soap

I am consuming soap api from my .net application. I am getting response from the soap api like this.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
    <ns2:getAuthKeyResponse xmlns:ns2="http://servicedesk.sims.tkd.com/">
        <return>VXNlcklEPTk5NzJ8fHx8QXV0aElEPTEzODYy</return>
    </ns2:getAuthKeyResponse>
</soap:Body>
```

How can i read the output in this case the authkey from the api response.

Comment: I am getting this response after reading the stream.

Comment: (1) Your XML is not well-formed, so you need to fix it by editing your original post. (2) Please share what you tried to do in .Net